# Who wrote the comments published within Avnei Miluim?

Tags: jewish-books, rabbis

The classic sefer Avnei Miluim (written by [R' Aryeh Leib HaKohein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryeh_Leib_Heller)) was published with many comments and annotations, although they are not credited.

I have heard various opinions on who the anonymous author was - some claim it was [R' Shlomo Yehuda "Shir" Rappaport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Judah_Loeb_Rapoport), who was the son-in-law of the author. Others claim it to be "R' Engel", although I don't know exactly who that might be.

Does anyone have any information or evidence on who the author was?

Comment: It was definitely shir

Answer (score 4):

Both of the people you mentioned have their notes published in Avnei Miluim.

Shir published the first section of the book in 1816, and included his notes at the end of the volume.

R. Yekutiel Asher Zalman Enzil Tzuzmir published the second section in 1825, and included his footnotes on a number of the pages.

Both of these individuals wrote and published introductions to the book, where they explain the notes that they included.

Shir's appears at the [end of Part I](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41124&st=&pgnum=174) where he writes:

> ונוסף ע"ז לקטתי אחת אחת כל התמיהות וצ"ע הבלתי מיושבות ודינים וענינים חדשים בזה הספר, וקבצתים וסדרתים על נכון לתועלת צעירי המעיינים, למען תת להם מקום וענין לענות בו. ובמעט מהם גליתי דעתי הקצרה, ועוררתי את המעיין על איזה דבר חדש ... לא בספר כתוב הבאתי דברי, כי אם בין שורות המפתחות הצפנתים, הרואה יראה והחדל יחדל

In most modern editions, R. Enzil's introduction appears at [the beginning of the book](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1807&st=&pgnum=5). He writes:

> ופעמים היתה תשועת ה' עמדי למצוא דבר חדש מתוך דבריו ז"ל לא נמנעתי מלהציגם ... והנה הצגתי ההערות ההן בשולי היריעה לבדנה. גם לפעמים העמדתי הגהה קטנה בתוך העמוד ואעש לה גדרות מזה ומזה.‏